# Why do so many cultures have a myth of the world being made or remade from water?

Tags: comparative, origins, creation, flood-myth

In various creation and flood myths the world is said to be remade from water, why would different ancient cultures have this same theme?

Comment: In many cases they just copy from one another. There are [historical studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Near_Eastern_Texts_Relating_to_the_Old_Testament) that indicate the biblical flood is based on Mesopotamian stories like  Ziusudra, Gilgamesh, and Atrahasis.

Comment: The ending of the last Ice Age (18000 to 8000 BC) saw a 120- meter rise of the sea level worldwide, that is 1.2m/100years, not much and people lived short lives. Nevertheless some form of memory probably persisted.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you were to start your own religion, you have to build principles of the, "Cycle of life," so as to explain life and death. To explain this cycle with respect to the world, you think of some ways for large scale destruction. What is something that's almost everywhere in the world? Something that can engulf the world, so as to start a new beginning? The seas, of course!
At least I feel that this line of thought is the reason for most of the myths.

Comment: Most religions don't have a concept of a cycle of life.  They believe that life is everlasting and therefore linear.  Also, look at the "start your own" religions that were created in the 20th Century.  None of those, that I'm aware of, have any principles of a cycle of life.